# Another magento move question but a bit reversed

Tags: magento2, transfer

I have a really silly question.
I have a live website that is hosted on a third party host and need to make a copy of it on my private server to be used as a staging environment. So far I have got the latest Magento 2 going on my Centos7 server after almost 2 weeks of mucking around.
I am aware that I have to copy the files from the magento directory on the live server which I have and the sql database which I have done also. 
But here is the thing, the live webiste is using Magento 2.1.5 I think, and my version I have installed is 2.3.0. Is this going to be a problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes it will cause problem because as per the version changes the code changes & also the usage of the data present into the database & the code changes. it would be better that if you will have the same version on the new server. Or better if you simply copy the code files & database to your new server from the old server!

Comment: Hi Abhishek, That is what I am thinking to do, copy the code and db from the live (older version of magento) server to the staging server (latest version of magento). Is that what you mean?

Comment: or for me to update the live website to the latest (same) version which I am hesitant to do.

Comment: yes! you should copy the live sites content to the staging site

Comment: OK doing it now. Moved the db and imported it, assigned full priv to the db user just like on the server. now mowing all the files to the root folder of magento.

Comment: So after I have done all the work of changing stuff in mysql and so on I am at this error on the staging environment:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Next Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/ar$
Stack trace:
#0 /home/arrowcs5/public_html/livedomain.com.auvendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Ab$
----------------------------------------------------

Comment: this directory /home/arrowcs5/public_html/l is set up on the live server and is not the same on the staging server. it should be /var/www/html .